# dplyr find minimum in x,y-plot

Tags: r, dplyr

to find and plot a minium in an X,Y-plot I made below, working code.
However I find it ugly and would expect something more elegant. The tibble, cf, contains in reality more then two variable. I reduced it to two only.

Who can provide me with more elegant code?

thx!!

=========

```
cf <- tibble(x = seq(0,pi,0.1), y = abs(cos(x)))

xlim <- cf %>%  filter(y < 0.5) %>% 
                arrange(desc(y)) %>% 
                top_n(1) %>% 
                select(x)

ggplot(cf, aes(x, y) ) +
  geom_point(size = 1, colour = "blue") +
  geom_hline(colour = "red", size = 1.2, yintercept = 0.5) +
  geom_vline(colour = "#99CCFF", size = 1, xintercept = as.numeric(xlim[1])) +
  labs(title = paste0("Y < 0.5 for X > ", as.numeric(xlim[1])))
```

Comment: 1) please try to avoid using function names such as `xlim` (used in [tag:ggplot]).  2) It is a bit unclear to me what you are exactly looking to get. What do you mean with 'plotting a minimum in an x,y plot' ??? I guess that the majority of plots have a minimum which will be plotted...

Comment: sorry I don’t understand this comment. If you want to add code to your question, edit your question directly. also you are introducing columns that have not been defined previously. (H1 and H2). Please detail your intention if you actually want help from us.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not being explicit enough. Before I used below base R code:

```
`
if ( length(cf[cf$y > 0.5, c("x")]) > 0 ) {
  xlim <- max(round(cf[cf$y > 0.5, c("x")],1))
} else {
  xlim <- min(round(cf$x,1))
}
`
```

which I re-implemented using dplyr. I wonder if I choose the best dplyr implementation, as it seems so lengthy to me:

```
`
    xlim <- cf %>%  filter(y < 0.5) %>% 
                     arrange(desc(y)) %>% 
                     top_n(1) %>% 
                     select(x)
`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most straightforward way of doing that with dplyr is as follows:

```
xl <- cf %>% filter(y < 0.5) %>% 
  filter(y == max(y)) %>% 
  select(x) %>% 
  as.numeric()
```

Note that with the last expression you can use the value just as a scalar:

```
ggplot(cf, aes(x, y) ) +
  geom_point(size = 1, colour = "blue") +
  geom_hline(colour = "red", size = 1.2, yintercept = 0.5) +
  geom_vline(colour = "#99CCFF", size = 1, xintercept = xl) +
  labs(title = paste0("Y < 0.5 for X > ", xl))
```